# Can't connect to Solr running Jetty on Ubuntu 10

Tags: tomcat, solr, jetty, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to get Solr setup on our Linode running Ubuntu 10 LTS.  We don't have a domain for this server yet so I'm just connect via the IP address  I've used Solr on other project without any problems.  I've tried to get solr (1.4) running with both jetty and tomcat from packages with little success.  The servers start but I cannot connect to them in the browser.  I've also downloaded the solr (3.5) example tar from the apache website which won't start all the way.  I have this gut feeling that this has something to do with the lack of a domain name, but it seems strange it won't resolve by just IP address.

My hope here is that someone could give me some ideas of what could be wrong in my configuration.

TIA

Comment: Can you ping its ip? Is Solr running? Can you see errors in the log file?

Comment: I can testify otherwise. My Ubuntu 10.04 server on Linode can access Solr as `xyz.members.linode.com:8080/solr` (before Solr was firewalled to the public world). Can you do a `curl http://localhost:1234/solr`

Comment: I can curl the loclahost but can't reach the xyz.members.linode.com:8080.  Which logfile should I be looking at for errors?  I'm not a java person; is there a logfile somewhere for all errors?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Oracle Java? Download the Oracle Java JRE from the Oracle website and install that. Remove any other Java version from your server, and then try again.

That sounds like it could be a RAM problem. Are you putting LOTS of documents into it? Are you monitoring it with `top` (press the M key to sort by memory usage) while you are doing this? If you are running low on RAM, that is likely the root of the problem.

SOLR keeps its index entirely in RAM. You need to allow enough RAM for the entire index as well as some extra for caching queries. I have a 9G database running on a machine with 12G of RAM and if I run a query like *:* for 1 million rows, then I run out of RAM and crash. That is because when SOLR caches a query it loads all the unindexed fields for the selected documents into RAM.

You can't effectively run SOLR on a small LINODE server. You need to get the biggest sizes. Actually, if your data will fit in the RAM of a small LINODE server, you might as well just build your own RAM index because you won't get much benefit from SOLR.

Comment: I just installed Oracle Java 7 and the downloaded Solr example running jetty still hangs.  I've never had a problem with this before.

Comment: Are you saying that you downloaded the SOLR tarball from Apache.org and are running the example server at `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/` ? Are you running the server from a console prompt? `java -jar start.jar 2>logfile` Then you can examine the logfile to see if there is something abnormal. Also, you could try Java 6 instead. SOLR is one of a number of applications that have run into problems with Java 7.

Comment: Correct, I'm just using the example server started from the console.  I've been paying attention to the output and there is nothing indicating why it's stalling.  I've tried a few different java environments, including OpenJDK 1.6.  Since I've got this working on a debian server I'm going to try it on that.

Comment: I was able to get this up and running in minutes on debian install.  Ram had nothing to do with the issue since it was a relatively small number of documents.